# Error applying drop shadow effect after initiation using PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6, qt6

I'm trying to apply a drop shadow effect on a QWidget after initiation but I get the following error:

`UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(860, 480), size=(344x256), dirty=(404x316 -20, -20) (The parameter is incorrect.)`

It works fine if I apply the effect inside the **init** function but not after that.

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect 
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class ShadowWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        self.button = QPushButton("Apply Shadow")
        self.button.setFixedSize(150, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.apply_shadow_effect)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        # self.apply_shadow_effect() # <- works fine

    def apply_shadow_effect(self):
        self.shadow_effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow_effect.setBlurRadius(15)
        self.shadow_effect.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 160))
        self.shadow_effect.setOffset(5, 5)

        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow_effect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ShadowWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

pressing the button in the example above yields the error.
I found someone with a similar error [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58602) but no solution was provided.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the drop shadow effect will **not** add a shadow beneath the window (eg. on the desktop or other windows), so if that's what you're trying to do, it wouldn't work anyway. Also, you should not use `setWindowFlags()` to specify `FramelessWindowHint`, but `setWindowFlag()` (without the "s") instead.

Comment: It is working as intended as long as I add the shadow during in the `__init__` method.

Comment: So, if you do that later, it does *not* work? Because you mention an error in the output, but that doesn't automatically mean that it doesn't work. Also, did you try to hide and show the window again after applying the effect? You probably need to do that with a `QApplication.processEvents()` between the calls, or, better, with a single shot QTimer: `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.show)` (eventually, try increasing the timeout value).

Comment: Correct, if I do it later it shows error and does _not_ work. You mean `setGraphicsEffect(...)` -> `self.hide()` -> `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.show)` ? That did also not work. I now get two of the same error message as before.